# How can installing winamp audio player app in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, package-management, sound, software-installation, audio-player

first of all I want to ask if the Winamp app can be used in Ubuntu? Because I have used that application for years, I have been using Ubuntu for about three years, and it seems to me better than Windows, but it is a bit complicated, because I don't know much about programming. A few days ago I downloaded some files with which I can supposedly install Winamp, but it is necessary to convert the files to .rpm, and other instructions and I'm having a hard time. I thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: There is a free version that is pretty close to Winamp. `sudo apt install qmmp`

Comment: Another alternative you may be interested in is [Audacious](https://audacious-media-player.org/). It can even use Winamp Classic skins.

Comment: The available instructions for installing Winamp version 3 from 2001 are specific to Red Hat Enterprise Linux. Your best bet is to try the Winamp-like music players that are available in Ubuntu first before you get too complicated with trying to install the Winamp 3 .rpm file in Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks friends, your help is very useful, I already installed QMMP, and it is very similar to winamp, I am going to install audacious to see how it works. thanks again